# Drawing multiple circles on canvas using JSON result

Tags: jquery, json, html, canvas

I have a need to draw several points on a canvas using data returned from a json call. The problem is that only one circle is showing even though the data contains 38 different points. Below is what I currently have.

```
<style>
       canvas, img { display:block;  }
       canvas { background:url(../../Content/Images/mapback.png) } 
</style>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1022" height="550" style="margin: 0 auto"></canvas>

<script>
var myData =  GetPlots();
var radius = 5;
    function GetPlots(){
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({async: false,
            url: "/Home/MapPlots",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            result = data;
        }});
        return result;
    };

    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    var ctx = mapCanvas.getContext("2d");

   for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(parseInt(myData[i].xCoord), parseInt(myData[i].yCoord), radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                ctx.fillStyle = myData[i].typeColor;
                ctx.fill();
    };
</script>
```

This is what my object looks like and is populated:

[image]

I have been all over the place trying to get this working and am only seeing one circle. Any ideas where I am going wrong? I've been all over google and everything I am finding says this is correct.

Comment: `plotData` vs `myData` ? Assume that is a typo. Try wrapping `for` loop in a closure

Comment: @charlietfl I miss typed it when I first asked the question. I have  corrected it. But its still giving me just 1 circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yCoord`s in your example object are 664 and 776, which are outside the bounds of your canvas height (550px).

One of the other objects must be within the bounds, which explains why it's the only one visible.